# JavaScript doesn't work in Mozilla Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, dom-events

I wrote the following code:

```
<form name=f>
<input type=button value="Button1" onclick=b1click()>
<input type=button value="Buttone2" onclick=b2click()>
<script language=javascript>
function b1click()
{
  f.action="Login.jsp";
  f.submit();
}
function b2click()
{
  f.action="Logout.jsp";
  f.submit();
}
</script>
</form>
```

This works code properly in Internet Explorer but the action does not work in Mozilla Firefox 3.6.2. How to solve this problem? Please any one help me.

Comment: "name" attribute is only used in <input> <select> or <textarea> tags, try using "id"

Comment: that is not true. Name can be used for a <form> tag http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_name.asp

Comment: @Radek S for me it has always worked as an easy to use reference for HTML and CSS, is there any information specifically false in the link I posted?

Answer (score 4):

I know this will sound snide, but the truth of the matter is: **it's not 1995 anymore**.

That code would have worked great a decade ago, but standards and specifications have changed significantly since then.

Lets start from the top:

```
<form name=f>
```

**All** html attribute values should be enclosed in quotes. For consistency sake, use double quotes: `<form name="f">` is much better.

```
<input type="button" value="Button1" onclick="b1click()">
```

Avoid inline-script events. If the functionality ever changes, or you want to remove a function, you'll have to go through *every* page and adjust the function. A better way is to give the button an ID, and add the onclick event via scripts:

```
HTML:
<input type="button" value="Button1" id="button1">
JS:
document.getElementById('button1').onclick = b1click;
```

Now the script's turn:

```
<script language=javascript>
```

You should use the `type` attribute with a valid [MIME type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mime_type). Additionally, whenever possible, move your scripts to an external script file. When that's not possible, make sure to either XML encode your script, or encase it in `CDATA` tags:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/script.js"></script>
```

OR

```
<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
... some code ...
/* ]]> */
</script>
```

Finally the real issue with your script.

The `f` property you're referencing is a member of the `document`, and **not** the `window`. I believe IE will put the reference on both, but it's just not safe to rely on either behavior.

Give the form an ID: `<form id="f">`, and get the element from the `b[12]click` functions

```
function b1click()
{
  var f = document.getElementById('f');
  f.action = 'Login.jsp';
  f.submit();
}
```

Comment: 'for consistency sake, use double quotes' nope. This is 50/50. For example, haml (which is **very** popular) renders single quotes by default.

Comment: What about HTML5? It doesn't use quotes (I was surprised. Validate http://flask.pocoo.org/) much.

Comment: @blender, not *requiring* quotes and not *using* quotes are two very different things. It's better to enclose your values in quotes just in case you want to do something silly, like use a space (i.e. `class=one two three` vs `class="one two three"` are very different). @Radek S, single quotes are fine. I prefer double quotes when working with PHP and JS, as I use single quotes in those languages.

Answer (score 2):

First off, change that `name="foo"` to `id="foo"`. Names are mostly used *within* the form itself.

Now, try to reference your form using `document.formID`, not just `formID`. `formID` is a variable, which is undefined, but `document.formID` is the actual form element:

```
function b1click()
{
  document.f.action="Login.jsp";
  document.f.submit();
}
function b2click()
{
  document.f.action="Logout.jsp";
  document.f.submit();
}
```

Comment: the changes proposed do nothing in Fx which works without them

Answer (score 1):

Give form an id and refer to it using:

```
var form = document.getElementById('formId');
```

Answer (score 0):

You should quote the input attributes, or any attributes for that matter.  And your `script` does not belong AFTER the form, e.g. in `body`, but rather in the HEAD element.

This works in IE, Firefox and Chrome.

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="javascript">
function b1click()
{
  f.action="Login.jsp";  // better is document.f., but f. appears to work as well
  f.submit();
}
function b2click()
{
  f.action="Logout.jsp";
  f.submit();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="f">
<input type="button" value="Button1" onclick="b1click()">
<input type="button" value="Buttone2" onclick="b2click()">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple ways to reference your form.

If you define your form as `<form name="Login" id="LoginFrom"></form>`,

**Method 1**

If your form is the only one in the page, you can use:

```
document.forms[0].action = 'Login.jsp';
```

**Method 2**

If your form is not the only one form in the page, you can use the form name to reference the form, such as

```
document.Login.action = 'Login.asp';
```

**Method 3**

The form can also be referenced with DOM function `getElementByID`.

```
document.getElementByID('LoginForm').action = 'Login.asp'
```